# Unable to negotiate a key exchange method [preauth]

Tags: linux, ssh

so recently i have been receiving the following errors in my bash console:

```
2017 Aug 31 19:32:06 home fatal: Unable to negotiate a key exchange method [preauth]
```

This is what i get in /var/log/auth/log:

```
Aug 31 19:32:06 home sshd[30975]: fatal: Unable to negotiate a key exchange method [preauth]
```

Is there any way i can trace what is trying to connect and then failing?

Anyone knows how to stop those messages from appearing (potentially fix the issue)?

Comment: What version of  `openssh` are you using?

Comment: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

Comment: This error was fixed in `Openssh 7`. I suggest you upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in `OpenSSH 7` See [here](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2461) for thread.

This message was caused due to attackers trying to login to your server. Don't worry this is normal. Welcome to the internet. Just create good passwords and disable root login and you should be good to go.

In `Openssh 7` you will see that it will look something like this:

```
localhost sshd[26793]: fatal: Unable to negotiate with 192.168.100.243: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 [preauth]
```

Comment: This solution worked, however do you know how i can make messages like this: 2017 Aug 31 20:14:17 ded fatal: no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com [preauth] not appear in my bash terminal?